# Storing multiple forms in extjs

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs

I am trying to store multiple form data in mysql database.
This is my code `Ext.extend(CaseRequirementGrid, Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel, {
    createRequirement: function(A, C, E){
        var B = this;
        C = C || "add";
        var D = new Ext.Window({
            id: "create-env-win",
            title: "Create Test Requirements",
            closable: true,
            width: 400,
        frame: true,
        bodyStyle: "padding:5px 5px 0",
            height: 230,
            plain: true,
            layout: "fit", 
            items: [{
            layout: "column",

        items: [{
                    xtype: "form",
                    url: "tr_list_requirements.cgi",
            bodyStyle: "padding: 10px",
                    id: "env_create_frm",
            columnWidth: 0.55,
            border: 0,
            height:450,
            frame: true,
            layout: "form",
                    items: [ new ProductCombo({
                    mode: "local",
                        fieldLabel: "Product",
                        value: B.product_id,
                        hiddenName: "product_id"
                    }), new TrackerTypeCombo({
                        hiddenName: "tracker_type",
            name: "tracker_type", 
                        id:"new_tracker_type",
                        mode: "local",
                        fieldLabel: "Tracker",
            allowBlank: false,
                    }),
                     {
                        xtype: "hidden",
                        name: "action",
                        value: C
                    }, {
                        xtype: "hidden",
                        name: "requirement_id",
                        value: E
                    }]
            },{
            xtype: "form",
            bodyStyle: "padding: 8px",
              url: "tr_list_requirements.cgi",
              id: "env_createext_frm",
                    columnWidth: 0.45,
            border: 0,
            height:450, 
            frame:true,
              layout: "form", 
                    items: [{
                        xtype: "field",
                        fieldLabel: "Parent Task",
                        inputType: "text",
                        name: "req_parenttask",
            hiddenName: "req_parenttask",
                        value: A != "" ? "Copy of " + A : "",
                        allowBlank: false
                        },{
                        xtype: "datefield",
                        fieldLabel: "Start Date",
                        name: "req_startdate",
            hiddenName: "req_startdate",
                        anchor: "50%",
                format: 'Y/m/d',
                        allowBlank: true
                        },{
                        xtype: "hidden",
                        name: "action",
                        value: C
                        }, {
                        xtype: "hidden",
                        name: "requirement_id",
                        value: E
                        }]
            }],
                    buttons: [{
                        text: "Create",
                        handler: function(){
                            Ext.getCmp("env_create_frm").getForm().submit({
                                success: function(F, G){
                                    Ext.Msg.alert('Status', 'Test Requirement ' + G.result.requirement_id + ' Created.');

                                    Ext.getCmp("create-env-win").close()
                    B.store.reload()
                                },
                                failure: testopiaError
                            })
                        }
                    }, {
                        text: "Cancel",
                        handler: function(){
                        Ext.getCmp("create-env-win").close()
                        }
                    }]
                }]
        });
        D.show(this)
    },`

But when i am trying to add the values it only stores values that are present in the first form and for the second form it adds Null values.
I tried adding another function to add the next form data but it throws me error

`Ext.getCmp("env_create_frm").getForm().submit({
                                success: function(F, G){
                                    Ext.Msg.alert('Status', 'Test Requirement ' + G.result.requirement_id + ' Created.');

                                    Ext.getCmp("create-env-win").close()
                    B.store.reload()
                                },
                                failure: Error
                            })
                        }
                    }`

Please suggest how to add multiple forms and suggest a good approach.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First, I want to recommend that you use legible variable names. Once everyone knows what exactly A, C and E are, coding will be much easier.

Furthermore I would like recommend that you post the ExtJS version you are using, if you need specific info that may be version dependent.

From what you are doing, I can guess that you want to have only ONE form to submit, but you want to have TWO panels next to each other with fields in them.

```
new Ext.Window({
    layout:'fit', // The form should take the whole window
    items:[{
        xtype:'form' // this is the ONE form
        layout:'column',
        url: "tr_list_requirements.cgi",
        items:[{
            xtype:'panel', // This is your form 1, but as a panel
            columnWidth: 0.55,
            border: 0,
            height:450,
            frame: true,
            ...
        },{
            xtype:'panel', // This is your form 2, but as a panel
            columnWidth: 0.45,
            border: 0,
            height:450,
            frame: true,
            ...
        }]
```